# Supervised instrument recognition

Tags: signal-detection, mfcc, classification, source-separation

Is it possible to use NMF for a sort of ***supervised*** polyphonic instrument recognition?

I have training data for a timpani and training data for a bongo (or a bongo, snare and box drum). How can I detect and classify them when they are played simultaneously, given the prior information?